# copy paste data to a row in another workbook, by updating columns while saving each time

Tags: vba, duplicates, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy paste a row from one workbook to another. There are 3 columns which will be updated on different dates, and each time I want to save it to destination it is not replacing the row, instead it is going to another row.  I want  code to replace the existing data every time I paste.I want to avoid pasting the existing column or update it so that the results are in one row.

```
 Else
    dstn = "S:\Radiotherapy-Department\Brachytherapy\Spreadsheets\Developement\Josmi_Project _ DB\Postsource exchangeResults.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (dstn)
    Sheets("Result-1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Range("M11:M12").Copy
    lastRow = Sheets("Result-1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Activate
End If
 
If Range("N11") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Confirm 'Pre & 1st Post'source exchange RAKR measurement completed"
Else
    dstn = "S:\Radiotherapy-Department\Brachytherapy\Spreadsheets\Developement\Josmi_Project _ DB\Postsource exchangeResults.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (dstn)
    Sheets("Result-1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Range("N11:N12").Copy
    lastRow = Sheets("Result-1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(lastRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Activate
End If
    
If Range("O11") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Confirm 'Pre & Post'source exchange RAKR measurement completed"
Else
    dstn = "S:\Radiotherapy-Department\Brachytherapy\Spreadsheets\Developement\Josmi_Project _ DB\Postsource exchangeResults.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (dstn)
    Sheets("Result-1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Range("O11:O12").Copy
    lastRow = Sheets("Result-1").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(lastRow, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Activate
End If
    
If Range("P11") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Confirm 'Pre & Post'source exchange RAKR measurement completed"
Else
    dstn = "S:\Radiotherapy-Department\Brachytherapy\Spreadsheets\Developement\Josmi_Project _ DB\Postsource exchangeResults.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (dstn)
    Sheets("Result-1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Range("P11:P12").Copy
    lastRow = Sheets("Result-1").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(lastRow, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORM.HDR 1.1").Range("M11:P12").ClearContents
    MsgBox "SOURCE STRENGTH VERIFICATION RESULTS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY"
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End If
```

Initial Table

[this is the first table. sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StpnO.jpg)

Result after saving the second time

[image]

Comment: It's difficult with any row/column headers to relate your code to the screenshots.

Comment: Just curious, Before running the sub, what is the value of "Without interuption" row under 1, 2 and 3 ? Is it a date ? and what is the valueof "With interuption" row under 1, 2 and 3 ? is it a percentage ? what does it mean _" There are 3 columns which will be updated on different dates"_ ? Does it mean that from those 3 columns (1,2,3 row without and with interuption), each column will be filled on different time for 3 times ? example ... (continue)

Comment: Say, at 1 pm, user input col 1 row without and with then run the sub - result is under 1st check. at 3 pm, user input col 2 row without and with then run the sub - result is under 2nd check. at 4 pm user input col 3 row without and with then run the sub - result is under check after 1 week. Please CMIIW.

Comment: yes. you are right.

Comment: so when we save result after final check, it should be in  1 row.

Comment: basically want to prevent the first code for first column from running again

Comment: finally, solved.  just added two lines of command.     ActiveSheet.Range("A:J").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Rows(lastRow + 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp